# Untrusted Valid Signature Tails-amd64-3.1.iso.sig

Tags: tails, tor-install

After download ISO and try to verify the ISO.sig comes up :

> tails-amd64-3.1.iso:Untrusted Valid Signature
>   Valid but untrusted signature by on 2017-08-09

So what is the play now? How bad is this situation? Should I download it again or it is safe to use it to upgrade my Tails?

Comment: you better attach full output of the GnuPG here - it will clarify your question. Now it's not 100% clear about what exactly the situation you do have and what to do in such a situation

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you don't understand OpenPGP/GnuPG you're recommended to use one of the non-expert installation methods. OpenPGP is there for experts only, as a non-expert you shouldn't use this installation method.

You can follow an easy to follow step-by-step process using the [Tails Installation Guide](https://tails.boum.org/install/index.en.html).

Comment: I suspect that you've misunderstood the Asker - looks like he knows how to work with GnuPG, but there're some weird output... I think the log will bring the light upon the situation

Comment: I have not misunderstood the asker and I have provided them with the correct information: *"So what is the play now?"*, to which the correct response is to use one of the alternative installation methods that doesn't involve verification with OpenPGP/GnuPG.